# mySQL UPDATE doesn't work for GAE when called from browser

Tags: python, mysql, google-app-engine, google-cloud-sql

I am writing a verify email address python file for Google App Engine. (ya I know django has stuff, but I wanted to write my own because that is how I learn)

Below is the python code. The code returns "Email Account Verified" which seems to me that the queries worked. However when I look at the "active" column in the database, it is still 0.

If I run the query string that logging.info("%s",db_query) in the database itself, it works and is updated to 1.

All my other python code (with UPDATES) works fine, the only difference is those python files are called from my ios app and this one is called from a browser.

```
#Make the libs folder with 3rd party libraries and common methods
import sys
sys.path.insert(0, 'libs')

#Imports
import logging
import webapp2
from django.utils.html import strip_tags
import common
import MySQLdb
import json

VERIFIED_HTML = """\
<html>
  <body>
    <h1>Email Account Verified</h1>
  </body>
</html>
"""

ERROR_HTML = """\
<html>
  <body>
    <h1>ERROR</h1>
  </body>
</html>
"""


class VerifyEmail(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        user_email = strip_tags(self.request.get('user_email').lower().strip())
        user_activation_hash = strip_tags(self.request.get('user_activation_hash').strip())

        logging.info("User Email = %s", user_email)
        logging.info("User Activation Hash = %s", user_activation_hash)

        #Insert the information into the users table
        #Get the database connection to Google Cloud SQL
        db = common.connect_to_google_cloud_sql()
        db_cursor = db.cursor(MySQLdb.cursors.DictCursor)

        #Check to see if user already exists
        #Query for user
        db_query = """SELECT \
                      email, activation_hash \
                      FROM users WHERE email='%s' AND activation_hash='%s'""" %          (user_email, user_activation_hash)
    db_cursor.execute(db_query)

        #If there is one record containing the username check password
        if(db_cursor.rowcount == 1):
            db_query = """UPDATE users SET active=%s WHERE email='%s';""" % (1, user_email)
            logging.info("%s" % db_query)
            if(db_cursor.execute(db_query)):
                self.response.write(VERIFIED_HTML)
            else:
                self.response.write(ERROR_HTML)

        else: #either no user, or activation_hash doesn't match
            self.response.write(ERROR_HTML)
```

Connect to Google Cloud SQL

```
def connect_to_google_cloud_sql():
    #hostname = DEV_DB_HOSTNAME
    #hostname = PROD_DB_HOSTNAME

    db_username = 'dummy_user' #not real
    db_password = 'dummypassword' # not real


    #If PROD or Deployed Testing, use unix_socket
    if(os.getenv('SERVER_SOFTWARE') and os.getenv('SERVER_SOFTWARE').startswith('Google App Engine/')):
      db = MySQLdb.connect(unix_socket='/cloudsql/' + _DATABASE_HOSTNAME, db='dummydbname', user=db_username, passwd=db_password)
    else: #Local Testing uses host
      db = MySQLdb.connect(host=_DATABASE_HOSTNAME, port=3306, db='dummydbname', user=db_username, passwd=db_password)

    logging.info("Got DB Connection")

    return db
```

Any suggestions? Is it GAE Cloud SQL Privledges????
Maybe because I was using my browser with the local app engine running on my local ip???

Comment: What a *perfect* example of an open SQL injection vector.

Comment: I am learning. If you want to help and give more info that would be appreciated.

Comment: @lr100, Daniel's point is "don't make SQL statements with string formatting" -- rather, use `%s` placeholders and call the two-argument form of `execute` (passing the tuple of values as the second argument).  It's a crucial vulnerability in your code as it stands but doesn't directly affect the error you observe.

Comment: Thanks Alex for explaining a little bit. I will look more into this.

Comment: Thanks for expanding my point, @AlexMartelli - I was commenting via mobile and couldn't type out the whole explanation. Great to see you back round these parts, BTW.

Comment: Appreciate the info. I really do. Can anyone also help me with the problem that is posted?

Comment: Can you post the content of `connect_to_google_cloud_sql()`, with your credentials hidden of course? I wonder if this would be helped by using transactions?

Comment: edited with the info you requests. thanks for taking a look at it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to call `.commit()` on MySQLdb cursors after executing queries. This is why your update is failing. It updates inside the transaction, but when your code ends without committing the transaction, the changes to the DB are rolled back, despite having told the user of success on update.

You can also use the following method to ensure commits when using a cursor: `db_cursor.autocommit(True)`.

Comment: Thanks so much!!! I hate when I make stupid mistakes but sometimes it takes another pair of eyes.